# SSRS: Getting Value From A Particular Textbox

Tags: function, visual-studio-2012, textbox, expression, ssrs-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 for SSRS purposes.

Currently, in my SSRS report, I have the following setup in my tablix/matrix:

[image]

Basically, I have row groups of Date and Mailbox and my first column is Starting which is number of records when starting of a particular date.

When I initially preview the report, this is what shows up:

[image]

Right now, in my total box, I have it as sum(starting) which is wrong and doesn't make sense. I basically want the First(Sum(Starting)) but I know SSRS is currently not allowing me to do that.

And I can't do First(Starting) because when I do my drilldown, it looks like this (I blurred out particular mailboxes):

[image]

So basically if I did First(Starting), it would pull in 25, instead of 339, because that's technically the first value.

How do I write an expression for the total line in Starting where I can get the first value that shows up underneath the Starting column where it is Sum(Starting) which in this case would be 339.

Answer (score 0):

Basically just had to write a different dataset to be just the value I needed then wrote an expression to grab that specific value from the dataset.